# Facebook Messenger notification sound doesn't work

Tags: notification

Lately I've installed FBmessenger in Ubuntu 13.04 following [these instructions](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/07/fb-messenger-and-facebook-applications.html)

The App worked fine: I could receive instant messages, see when someone commented my posts and so on, except notification sounds for new messages. They just don't work even though I checked the option "Chat Sounds": see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yrUc.jpg)

Help me, please, to figure out how to enable these sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be your system event sounds are off. install Ubuntu tweak tool and then open it. Then at tweak tab you can find sounds like this from there you can manage [image]